# ERROR: dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, face-recognition, dlib

while downloading the dlib module, the terminal output returns with an error:

CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

```
    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

Comment: Do you try what it suggested: To fix this problem, run cmake from the Visual Studio Command Prompt

Answer (score 3):

Alright. I was installing `dlib` for quite a while. I know what NOT to do now.
The only thing you need is this.
Follow the steps. That is it. Turns out that `dlib` is not supported by the pythons latest version. So you have to install a  `python wheel` which is easy to install by the command `pip install wheel` on your `cmd` . Then after downloading the files mentioned [Follow the steps mentioned in the git profile below, you'll be good.]

It gets kind of stressful to install all the things separately. The link below runs a setup to install the `dlib` package. It will ask your user permission to run and will be blocked by the windows defender, but press more and click on "Run anyways".
Don't forget to test your package installation !

https://github.com/shashankx86/dlib_compiled

Answer (score 1):

Issues got fixed by trying below solutions

1. **Try installation using wheel files
   Even it gets failed due to platform unsupport, please try the below options**
2. **Try to installing the source files from https://pypi.org/project/dlib/#files and run pip setup.py install by placing your files into site packages folder.
   If its shows any ssize_t variable issue in numpy, please declare a local variable ssize on the top of the file**

Answer (score -1):

check this link for installation on ubuntu or mac os platform https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/22/install-dlib-easy-complete-guide/

The another type installation method if you are using dlib for face_recognition models then follow this answer

(with python 3.6 to 3.7.0 working normally).

First create an environment , **conda create -n env_name python=version**

then activate, **conda activate env_name**

now install via conda forge channel, **conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24492837)

Comment: Please check complete details of an answer before downgrade it

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I encountered it in a review, and commented. Link-only answers are considered low-quality, because links to outside resources have tendencies to lead in the void after some time passes and resource becomes unavailable

Comment: I will remind this here after. thanks for your support